# 1 Script, Many users, 1 server: Attempting to create a script that will use ssh or another login method to allow many users to connect to 1 server

Tags: linux, ssh, scripting, server

I currently have a script that connects to user@server.com via sftp. This is using a ssh key created on my current machine that I'm using for testing purposes. Below is a quick example of my script. I've tried finding a solution online but I don't seem to be looking in the right locations.

```
sftp user@server.com << EOF
put file.csv
exit
EOF
```

What I want is for many clients to be able to run this script and automatically connect to the server without each one having their own ssh key that we need to approve on the server side.

Comment: I would say that SSH/SFTP is not really the right tool to do something like this. Use an FTP server instead and allow anonymous access.

Comment: The problem with this would be the lack of security.

Comment: And having unrestricted access via SFTP/SSH or sharing SSH keys would not be a security risk? I don't get that argument at all. :D If you use a proper FTP server, you can at least limit the access to a single folder.